# How to pass global variable to Gearman worker (PHP)

Tags: php, global-variables, gearman

My Gearman workers need to connect to my database. How can I pass a reference to my global `$db` variable? In the code below, `$db` is undefined in the `executeJob` function.

```
$db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name, $db_port);

// set up Gearman worker
$worker = new GearmanWorker();
$worker->addServer();
$worker->addFunction("execute", "executeJob");
while($worker->work());

function executeJob($job) {
    global $db;
    print_r($db); \\ UNDEFINED
}
```

The php manual suggests that context data can be passed when setting up the worker function with [addFunction](http://php.net/manual/en/gearmanworker.addfunction.php), but it's not clear to me if that's what I need or even how to do it. Thanks!!

Comment: Does this code happen to be inside a function...?

Comment: No, the snippet above is not within a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, context data is what you need.

```
$db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name, $db_port);

// set up Gearman worker
$worker = new GearmanWorker();
$worker->addServer();
$worker->addFunction("execute", "executeJob", $db);
while($worker->work());

function executeJob($job, $db) {
    print_r($db);
}
```